# Manjaro with MariaDB slow Laravel database seeding

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb, seeding

I have a Manjaro installation on an HDD with a MariaDB server running. Seeding my database with `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` takes a very long time (~100rows/sec).

It's seeding 70000 rows in a table with random data. I previously attempted this seed on a different PC with WAMP and it took around 15 seconds all together.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: You should be comparing the performance between Manjaro and MariaDB vs PC and WAMP on the same machine otherwise there's always the chance this is just due to different hardware

Comment: Are you chunking the inserts? You’ll get much better performance if you use array_chunk and DB::insert